# Need to know if the magic __call() request is expecting a return result

Tags: php

Essentially, I want to enact different behavior in the following two scenarios.

```
<?php
$foo = Bar();
echo $foo->baz(1);
$foo->baz(1);
```

I want to handle "echo $foo->baz(1)" differently because the call is expecting a return result.

I am wiring up these calls to a pl/sql backend, where pl/sql cares deeply for the difference between a function and a procedure. Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: No, there isn't. Functions and methods can't know if run from within an expression or as statement. Because function call statements are just void expressions themselves.

Comment: You can't do that with regular methods and functions. What makes you think this will work? Besides, a method that behaves differently depending on the way it's called has an awful bad code smell. What you're proposing is a fundamentally unsound idea.

Comment: Could you tell us more about how you're looking PHP up to pl/sql?  Couldn't you just have whatever glue code is making the call just discard the return value as needed?

Comment: @NullUserException: Fundamentally I agree. However it is functionally important in this situation because the call ultimately gets wired up to PL/SQL which does care about whether a return value is required.

Comment: @Charles: Certainly. We are building a sort of ORM mapping to our database tables.

For example, if we have a class named Toll_Free, then the superclass knows how to automatically call a certain package that has all of the logic for insert, updates and deletes on the table.

In PL/SQL we would then expect to also have Type named TOLL_FREE, which will then have methods specific to this table, such as CHANGE_ACCOUNT. Some methods are procedures, others functions, and then can be static or instance methods.

I hope that is clear enough.

Comment: @Charles: We are going to do what you suggest. For every PL/SQL procedure we will have a corresponding function that just calls that procedure and returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not understand what you want to achieve(in other words, what *"I want to handle `echo $foo->baz(1)` differently"* means exactly). But if you need to know if the result of the  `$foo->baz(...)` was echoed or not, you can write `baz()` method to return object which implements `__toString()` method, where you can do your heavy strange magic...